# Hugging Face | tokenizer.batch_encode_plus inconsistent columns on different datasets

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, xgboost, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Im currently using tokenizer.batch_encode_plus and the same tokenizer is applied to different datasets/list of text. df_train_feats and df_test_feats produce different column lengths.

```
df_test_feats.shape
Out[2]: (2, 8)

df_train_feats.shape
Out[3]: (2, 20)
```

Due to this inconsistent column name, it will result in an error when passing it to xgboost model.

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd

import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
str_token = 'distilbert-base-uncased'


if __name__ == '__main__':
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        
        model_check_point = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
        model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_check_point)
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_check_point, add_prefix_space=True, use_fast=False)
        df_train_feats_encoded = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(["today I went to the movies ", "today I went to the movies and had dinner at saints a new resturant in italy"], max_length=20, padding=True)
        df_train_feats = pd.DataFrame(df_train_feats_encoded['input_ids'])
        
        df_test_feats_encoded = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(['we could not play paddal','it rain most of the afternoon'], max_length=20, padding=True)
        df_test_feats = pd.DataFrame(df_test_feats_encoded['input_ids'])
```

How do I fix this so the the input data to the xgboost has the same dataframe shape or the outputs from the tokenizer is consistent regardless of the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizers pad to the longest value in their *current* input.
**Tokenizing two independent batches are likely to have different shapes**.

E.g.

```
>>> tokenize([["Hello World"], 
              ["Hello There Mister"]])
[[123, 533, <pad>],
 [123, 3535, 6834]]
```

```
>>> tokenize([["Hello World"], 
              ["Hello There Mister X Y Z"]])
[[123, 533, <pad>, <pad>, <pad>, <pad>],
 [123, 3535, 6834, 58, 59, 60]]
```

So you either have to tokenize everything together and then split it into train and test, or pad the smaller outputs manually to be of size of the larger set.

Comment: It will work however in a real world situation it will not be ideal. When the model is placed into production it will experience a problem with live data. I found a work around, for all missing columns names, I added it to the test set and stored that column with zero. The downfall is that due to the sequential nature of LLMs, column feature between the test and train set will not be represented correctly.